# Checking whether an ideal is inside another.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ideals

I want to determine whether this ideals are contained in each other or not.

1) In $\mathbb{R}[x]$, $I_1= \langle x(1+x^2) \rangle$ and $I_2= \langle x^2(1+x) \rangle$. I can see that $I_1 \not\subseteq I_2$, since $I_2$ has $x$'s of degree 2 or higher, whereas in $I_1$ we have elements of degree 1. However, I don't know how to check that $I_2 \not\subseteq I_1$. Does anyone have any suggestion?

2) In $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$, consider $I_1= \langle (y-x^2)^2+(y-x^3)^4 \rangle$ and $I_2= \langle (y-x^2)^4 + (y-x^3)^2 \rangle$. In this one, I really don't know how to check that neither is contained in the other. Any hints or suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To check if $\langle f \rangle \not\subseteq \langle g \rangle$, it is necessary and sufficient to check that $f/g$ is not a polynomial in the ring, i.e. $g$ does not divide $f$.